# Usability Problems with RDP and Dual Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, split-window

When I RDP into a win2k3 machine with the dual mon settings, I've noticed that there are a couple of usability problems:

1) Dialog boxes are popped up right in the middle of both monitors making it hard to read.

2) Windows are maximized to both monitors instead of just one.

3) The task bar spans across two monitors. (This is just a matter of preference. I prefer my task bar to span across just my primary monitor)

I know that [Splitview](http://www.splitview.com/) is a good tool that solves all these problems, but there's a price-tag to it. To be fair, $39 for a tool like this is not too bad at all.

However, before I suggest this tool to my team and manager to get the licenses for it, are there any free alternatives that will solve the 3 above problems?

-Steve

Comment: Anyone else has any other answers?

Answer (score 1):

There are many limits from Windows RDP services.

To upgrade your dual-monitor experiences, you will have to upgrade your server to 2008 R2 and using RDP client 7.0.

You can read more from this
[http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/archive/2009/08/21/remote-desktop-connection-7-for-windows-
7-windows-xp-windows-vista.aspx][1]

[1]: http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/archive/2009/08/21/remote-desktop-connection-7-for-windows- 7-windows-xp-windows-vista.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look into the video card manufacturer and see if they have any applications that work for dual monitors. I know that NVidia has an application (I can't remember the name) that I use for my workstation at work. It allows me to customize all of the things you mentioned, including which applications allow children windows (think window inside of window like Excel workbooks and sheets) to span both monitors.

Addendum: I'm not sure if this software will work with RDP, it is a free download though, so worth checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window positioning hotkeys in [WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) or [DisplayFusion](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/) to address the second problem, and possibly also the first problem.

Unfortunately, you probably need a different RDP client to show the Terminal Server's taskbar on only one screen (or you need to move the taskbar to the left or right side, instead of the bottom).